# Correct encoding for Asian CJK characters on Windows MYSQL 5.5.10?

Tags: mysql, character-encoding, cjk

Having problems saving CJK characters to my MYSQL DB, question marks are shown in DB. I've tested client input by writing to text file and this seems fine, so I expect the problem is on the server and perhaps a Windows issue. Can anyone help with this?

My character set variables are:

```
+--------------------------+----------------------------------------+
| Variable_name            | Value                                  |
+--------------------------+----------------------------------------+
| character_set_client     | utf8                                   |
| character_set_connection | utf8                                   |
| character_set_database   | latin1                                 |
| character_set_filesystem | binary                                 |
| character_set_results    | utf8                                   |
| character_set_server     | latin1                                 |
| character_set_system     | utf8                                   |
+--------------------------+----------------------------------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

Although I'd made a change to my database table to chang Collation from Latin1 to UTF8 this didn't change existing encoding. I had to edit table data and changed all required columns from Latin1 to UTF8. Saving as CJK now works fine.